# Navigation - SplitView or Pivot

Tags: user-interface, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I'd like to ask you, what do you think, which control is better for navigation. What I mean?
Now I have Pivot control with 2 PivotItems. One of them is named Contacts. This PivotItem contains Frame. And the frame makes new navigation on page with contacts (listview). Why Frame? When I click on some contact I need to show details of current contact. But I need to display it inside PivotItem, therefore I use inner frame. So I can still see main view and other pivot items. I think, that pivot is not right control for it. Or I should show contact details for whole screen, not only in pivotitem.

> FrameA and FrameB. FrameA has navigated from Main to Page1. Page1 has a Pivot that hosts FrameB in PivotItem1 and FrameB has navigated from View1 to View 2 and from View2 to View 3

Comment: The question, while formed like an opinion-based question, making it a candidate for closing - seems to be more about Windows-native design patterns and so I think it deserves to remain open.

Comment: You should consider a few things - what will be the most common usage scenarios, what devices you're targeting, what your users are most used to, what solutions are available and how much time you have. In your scenario, I would consider checking the Photos app. You have a pivot with a few different views of your data (classic Windows Phone 7 design), then when you click a photo - it navigates to another page with a FlipView. You could do the same, but Photos are not contacts. On PC you could fit both the list (pivot) and details together... until you resize. Check what Voice Recorder does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start reading up on [navigation basics for Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-basics) and look at some other apps how they do it.

You could use a navigation pane (which is mostly done using a `SplitView`), in which you show your contacts grid in the main panel and navigate to a single contact when clicking on it. The other item in your navigation pane would be the title for your 2nd pivot tab.

[image]

If you want to keep your contact list visibile at all time and show the details of a single contact next to it, the alternative is using master-detail. Either on a full screen, or by placing the master detail on the main panel of your `SpltView`.

[image]

You can find a master-detail control in the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit).

Comment: I wouldn't go that way no. Because if you're on mobile and swipe in the inner frame, you might trigger the pivot to go to the 2nd tab.

Comment: I would not swipe frame. Frame contains listview with contacts and when I click on some contact, I navigate in this frame on contact detail page. so no swiping. But I think too, that it's not good approach, but our teamleader told me, to do that :/

Comment: Sometimes it's better to do what's right and sometimes it's better do what you're asked to do. The trick is to decide out which way you're gonna go. :)